# Does Rinkeby have a faucet where I can fill a wallet with DAI?

Tags: testnets, rinkeby, dai

I'm looking to use a testnet to test an application. I know I can get ether, but is there an easy way I could convert it to Dai? Thanks

Comment: Why do you need DAI in Rinkeby? As alternative you can deploy your own ERC20 token in Rinkeby.

Comment: Would like to test an application that runs on Rinkeby

Comment: Any news on this? Did you solve this? I'm also struggling to get DAI (on Kovan though, but Rinkeby would help too).

Comment: No, I wasn't able to find a solution. I just ended up using a ETH test faucet instead.

Answer (score 8):

Go to "https://app.compound.finance/" connect metamask using rinkeby test network
In supply section select DAI -> Faucet[image]

Answer (score 7):

I deployed a mock ERC20 on all Ethereum testnets (Goerli, Kovan, Rinkeby and Ropsten) so you don't have to:

- Goerli at [0x97cb342Cf2F6EcF48c1285Fb8668f5a4237BF862](https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x97cb342Cf2F6EcF48c1285Fb8668f5a4237BF862)
- Kovan at [0x79dfab686Ef87cd2c871D5182F08538589234189](https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0x79dfab686Ef87cd2c871D5182F08538589234189)
- Rinkeby at [0x5eD8BD53B0c3fa3dEaBd345430B1A3a6A4e8BD7C](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x5eD8BD53B0c3fa3dEaBd345430B1A3a6A4e8BD7C)
- Ropsten at [0x3ac1c6ff50007ee705f36e40F7Dc6f393b1bc5e7](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x3ac1c6ff50007ee705f36e40F7Dc6f393b1bc5e7)

You can mint as many tokens as you wish by calling the `mint` function on Etherscan. Just makes sure you have [MetaMask](https://metamask.io) connected and click one of the addresses above.

The source code for the contract can be found [here](https://github.com/paulrberg/contracts/blob/v3.2.0/contracts/token/erc20/GodModeErc20.sol).

Comment: How do I call mint()? Can I do that from metamask? Or from a js program running on a page that connects to metamask lib?

Comment: @Tomachi I updated my answer to be more specific. You have to use Etherscan.

Comment: for beginners like me: click on the address, go to Contract and then select Write Contract then click on Connect to Web3 to connect your wallet and finally call the mint function.